# Calling web service with unknown name of method

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

Need to call web method, from web service.
but name of method is unknown at compile time, so i can not use vs proxy generated class for webservice. 
So, how can i define name of method at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

- Pull the method name from some xml config file
- Call the web service using reflection, [Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62365/using-reflection-to-call-an-asp-net-web-service/62381#62381), [Example 2](http://www.builderau.com.au/program/web/soa/Applied-Reflection-Creating-a-dynamic-Web-service-to-simplify-code/0,339024632,339271837,00.htmhttp://www.builderau.com.au/program/web/soa/Applied-Reflection-Creating-a-dynamic-Web-service-to-simplify-code/0,339024632,339271837,00.htm), [Example 3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730835(v=vs.80).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [post](http://dotnetslackers.com/Community/blogs/kaushalparik/archive/2010/05/14/how-to-call-invoke-a-web-service-without-adding-web-reference.aspx). It involves calling `wsdl` to generate proxy for the webservice when required.

Comment: sry, but i see only how he changes URL of service, but question is a bit diffrent

Comment: OK. look here - related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277212/how-to-call-a-web-service-with-no-wsdl-in-net